# ElasticSearch + Kibana - Unique count using pre-computed hashes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

**update**: Added

I want to perform unique count on my ElasticSearch cluster.
The cluster contains about 50 millions of records.

I've tried the following methods:

### First method

Mentioned in [this section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_pre_computed_hashes):

> Pre-computing hashes is usually only useful on very large and/or high-cardinality fields as it saves CPU and memory.

### Second method

Mentioned in [this section](https://www.found.no/foundation/sizing-elasticsearch/#field-data-and-document-values):

> Unless you configure Elasticsearch to use doc_values as the field data format, the use of aggregations and facets is *very* demanding on heap space.

### My property mapping

```
"my_prop": {
  "index": "not_analyzed",
  "fielddata": {
    "format": "doc_values"
  },
  "doc_values": true,
  "type": "string",
  "fields": {
    "hash": {
      "type": "murmur3"
    }
  }
}
```

### The problem

When I use unique count on my_prop.hash in Kibana I receive the following error:

```
Data too large, data for [my_prop.hash] would be larger than limit
```

ElasticSearch has 2g heap size.
The above also fails for a single index with 4 millions of records.

### My questions

1. Am I missing something in my configurations?
2. Should I increase my machine? This does not seem to be the scalable solution.

### ElasticSearch query

Was generated by Kibana:
http://pastebin.com/hf1yNLhE

### ElasticSearch Stack trace

http://pastebin.com/BFTYUsVg

Comment: What is the complete error message (including stacktrace)?

Comment: And what is the query that fails?

Comment: Since you are already using `doc_values` for `my_prop` I suggest doing the same for `my_prop.hash` (and, no, the settings from the main field are not inherited by the sub-fields): `"hash": {
      "type": "murmur3", "index" : "no",
"doc_values" : true
    }`

Comment: That error says you don't have enough memory to store all the values from `hash`, so you need to take them out from the heap and put them on disk, meaning using `doc_values`.

Comment: I'm having a problem with your solution. See new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781207/elasticsearch-doc-value-in-murmur3-hash

Comment: Well? Works for you now? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error says you don't have enough memory (more specifically, memory for `fielddata`) to store all the values from `hash`, so you need to take them out from the heap and put them on disk, meaning using `doc_values`.

Since you are already using `doc_values` for `my_prop` I suggest doing the same for `my_prop.hash` (and, no, the settings from the main field are not inherited by the sub-fields): `"hash": { "type": "murmur3", "index" : "no", "doc_values" : true }`.